# How can I continue building Ionic iOS apps without a mac?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, mac-in-cloud

As an Ionic/Cordova app developer on Windows, I've been using PhoneGap Build to create and sign my iOS apps before using MacInCloud to upload them to the App Store via App Loader. Unfortunately as of today, Apple requires iOS SDK 13 for uploading apps to the App Store. PhoneGapBuild does not support SDK 13 yet and there's no roadmap or idea of when it will start.

As I mentioned, I use MacInCloud to upload my apps and I'm curious if anyone has a way to remotely build the apps on iOS outside of uploading all of my code and using the Cordova or Ionic CLI via Remote Desktop.

Or hey, maybe you as a developer on PC have another way to build iOS apps. I've very interested in hearing how you're building apps now that PhoneGap Build is no longer an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to Create a macOS Catalina Virtual Machine with VirtualBox !!

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/appflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave the VirtualBox route a shot and wow, that was messy. I ended up just settling with logging into my MacInCloud account every time I was to create an iOS build and just dealing with that. Much cheaper solution than appflow.